# Python mock patch with sub module

Tags: python, django, unit-testing, python-mock

I'm having trouble replacing a simple method that calls a function in another module. From what I understand of mocking, you have to reference the method being called (in it's context, and not the original). Below is a simplified version of what I'm running and hoping that it's something simple that I need to learn about mocks. Is patch intended to be used only for Class and Class methods or am I doing something else wrong here?

Thanks,
Steve

**myapp.models.py**

```
from myapp.backends import get_backend
class BasicClass(models.Model):
    @staticmethod
    def basic_method()
        be = get_backend()
        print be
```

**myapp.backends._*init*_.py**

```
def get_backend():
    return 'original value'
```

**test.py**

```
# Referencing the import in myapp.models.basic_class 
# vs directly importing myapp.backends
# as indicated here: 
# http://www.voidspace.org.uk/python/mock/patch.html#where-to-patch
from myapp.models import get_backend
from myapp.models.basic_class import BasicClass

class ParsersTest(TestCase):

    @patch('myapp.models.get_backend')
    def test_simplified(self, moves_backend):
        # Assertion fails
        assert get_backend is moves_backend
        # Assuming that assertion fails is why the original return value is always returned
        moves_backend.return_value = 'new return value'
        BasicClass.basic_method()
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The purpose of patching with mock is to replace the reference to a module as it would be stored in `sys.modules` and replace it with a reference to your mock.  These means that code *in the patched module* will receive a reference to the mock object.

In your test, you are working with `get_backend`.  Which was imported at the top of your test module directly from `myapp.models` before the decorator was applied.  It is not patched.  Your patch is in place, but only for code in `myapp.models` which reference the `get_backend` symbol imported there.

I know that's confusing.  For me it was the hardest part of getting started with mock.  If your test looked like this:

```
class ParsersTest(TestCase):

    @patch('myapp.models.get_backend')
    def test_simplified(self, moves_backend):
        from myapp.models.basic_class import BasicClass

        # Assertion should pass
        BasicClass.basic_method()
        moves_backend.assert_called_with()

        moves_backend.return_value = 'new return value'
        # As should this one (if you change the method to return instead of print)
        self.assertEqual(BasicClass.basic_method(), 'new return value')
```

I think your test would be passing.  The key difference here is that you are not testing against get_backend directly.  You are testing a method that uses an imported get_backend after the patch has been applied.

**update**

The only other thing I can think of, without getting my hands on your actual code, is just that I don't like using patch as a decorator because you get less control over when the patch is applied/removed and worrying about getting a reference to the mock via args.

Try the context manager style:

```
with mock.patch('my app.models.get_backend') as moves_backend: 
      #...
```

with the rest of the test logic nested under that branch.

**update part II**

I just noticed in your original code that `BasicClass` is in `myapp.models.basic_class.py`.

If that's the case you patch should be applied to `'myapp.models.basic_class.get_backend'` because you are wanting to patch the reference to `get_backend` that is being imported in the `myapp.models.basic_class`submodule.

Comment: Made an update to this pseudo test.  The original assertion I made was totally wrong.

Comment: Thanks @Casey. I gave that a shot and it's still calling the original method. Any other weird nuances with Mock that you can recommend?

Comment: Formatting was lost on my comment so I updated my answer with more details.

Comment: after digging around my code, both your initial suggestion and the updated 'with mock.patch' worked flawlessly.

Answer (score 0):

I think you misunderstand. Remember: in Python, module and class members are (more or less) just simple variables. They might happen to contain a method, but they're still just variables. When you import something from another module, it just creates a variable on the importing module and drops some object into it.

The decorator `@patch('myapp.models.get_backend')` just replaces the variable on the `myapp.models` with a mock object. This is not what you want. By the time the patch is applied, `myapp.models.basic_class` has already been imported, so it has already imported a reference to the real method from `myapp.models`. (In other words, its `get_backend` variable holds the real method already.) You want to replace the variable where it's actually being used in `myapp.models.basic_class` like so:

```
@patch('myapp.models.basic_class.get_backend')
```

This will fill the `get_backend` variable on the `myapp.models.basic_class` with a mock. So when you call `BasicClass.basic_method()`, `basic_method` will look inside the `myapp.models.basic_class.get_backend` variable and find a mock.

So try this:

```
from myapp.models import basic_class

class ParsersTest(TestCase):
    @patch('myapp.models.basic_class.get_backend')
    def test_simplified(self, moves_backend):
        assert basic_class.get_backend is moves_backend
        moves_backend.return_value = 'new return value'
        basic_class.BasicClass.basic_method()
```

All that said, be careful what you test. You don't want to test everything in every possible way. Consider what value this test is providing you before writing it.

Comment: Thanks @jpmc26, you astutely noticed the wrong path for BasicClass. With the corrected path, is my test patch still correct? Thanks also for the detailed reminder of class members.

Comment: @daxiang28 Assuming that `from myapp.models.basic_class import BasicClass` is also a typo, I believe so.

Comment: @daxiang28 I know you've already solved your problem, but I was incorrect before. `from myapp.models import get_backend` occurs too early for your code to work correctly. It will hold a reference to the real method, before it is patched. You should still do `from myapp import models` and then `assert models.get_backend is moves_backend`.

Comment: thanks for the update. That's what I ultimately did. Mocks took me a while to fully wrap my head around, but eventually it all makes sense now.

Comment: Just to be clear, I would never expect to see that particular `assert` in real life code. I was assuming you just had it there as kind of a test to figure out how things work.